# PHP composer install PHPUnit runner

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

I am trying to install PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php using PHP composer and I get the following error.

- The requested package phpunit/phpunit-runner could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

I am not sure if I am install the wrong package or what. The following is what I have in my composer.json file.

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.*",
        "phpunit/php-invoker": "*",
        "phpunit/dbunit": ">=1.2",
        "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.2",
        "phpunit/phpunit-story": "*",
        "phpunit/phpunit-runner": "*" - with this removed that file is unavailable
    }
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: The only `phpunit-runner` package I could find is [https://github.com/slavahatnuke/hot-phpunit-runner](https://github.com/slavahatnuke/hot-phpunit-runner). Did you mean that one?

Comment: I don't think so. It's part of this thread. https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1167. It should loading this file https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/4.0/src/Runner/Version.php#L57.

Comment: Yes, I found the same thing. What is the package called then? Is it suppose to be part of a different package? I sent an email out to PHPUnit test trying to figure it out. I have installed it before with PEAR but it seems they are no longer adding to PEAR.

Answer (score 1):

The class `PHPUnit_Runner_Version` is part of the core PHPUnit package `phpunit/phpunit` [in any version](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Runner/Version.php).

So there is no need to require it seperately because the package name you invented does not exist.

You probably have a different problem you didn't ask in this question about some software not being able to require this class, but this likely isn't being solved this way.